# runtime error while trying to run .Net application

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an error while trying to run this code on remote server.
I'm getting this error everytime I try to run this code.

I even couldn't figure out what is and error in this file, this remote server doesn't show me any errors.
http://labwebs.webster.edu/gmakharadze78/coap2100/fig23-13.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="JScript" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<!-- Fig. 23.13: adRotator.aspx  -->
<!-- ASP.NET AdRotator example   -->

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Ice Creams</title>

      <script language = "JScript" runat = "server">

         function submitButton_Click( 
            sender : Object, events : EventArgs ) : void 
         {
            if ( IsPostBack ) 
            {
               if ( iceCream.SelectedItem == "Yes" ) 
               {
                  message.Text = name.Text + " likes ice cream.";
               }
               else 
               {
                  message.Text = name.Text + " does not like ice cream.";
               }
            }

         } // end submitButton_Click
      </script> 
   </head>

   <body>
      <form action = "adRotator.aspx" method = "post" runat = "server">   

         <asp:AdRotator AdvertisementFile = "ads.xml" 
            BorderColor = "black" BorderWidth = "1" runat = "server"/>

         <table>
            <tr>
               <td> 
                  Name: <asp:TextBox id = "name" runat = "server"/> 
               </td>
               <td> 
                  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id = "requiredCheck"
                     ControlToValidate = "name"
                     Display = "Static"
                     runat = "server">
                     Please enter your name.
                  </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

         <br />
         Do you like ice cream?         

         <asp:RadioButtonList id = "iceCream" runat = "server">
            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:RadioButtonList>         

         <br />    
         How many scoops would you like? (0-5)     

         <asp:TextBox id = "scoops" runat = "server" /> 

         <br />
         <asp:button text = "Submit" OnClick = "submitButton_Click"
            runat = "server"/>

         <asp:RangeValidator id = "rangeCheck"
            ControlToValidate = "scoops"
            MinimumValue = "0"
            MaximumValue = "5"
            Type = "Integer"
            EnableClientScript = "false"
            Text = "We cannot give you that many scoops."
            runat = "server" />

         <center>             
            <h1> <asp:label id = "message" runat = "server"/> </h1>
         </center>

      </form>
   </body>
</html>

<!--
**************************************************************************
* (C) Copyright 1992-2004 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
* Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
*                                                                        *
* DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
* best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
* development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
* to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
* no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
* programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
* and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
* consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
* furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
**************************************************************************
-->
```

Here's .xml file for this application.

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<!-- Fig. 23.14: ads.xml  -->
<!-- Flag database        -->

<IceCreams>

   <IceCream>
      <ImageUrl>img/Chocolate.png</ImageUrl>
      <ImageUrl>img/Mix.png</ImageUrl>
      <NavigateUrl>http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/chocolate-ice-cream-recipe.html</NavigateUrl>
      <AlternateText>Chocolate IceCream</AlternateText>

   </IceCream>

   <IceCream>
      <ImageUrl>img/Strawbery.png</ImageUrl>
      <ImageUrl>img/Ice.png</ImageUrl>
      <NavigateUrl>http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/jamie-deen/strawberry-and-cream-ice-cream-recipe.html</NavigateUrl>
      <AlternateText>Strawbery IceCream</AlternateText>

   </IceCream>

   <IceCream>
      <ImageUrl>img/Vanilla.jpeg</ImageUrl>
      <ImageUrl>img/All.jpg</ImageUrl>
      <NavigateUrl>http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/vanilla-ice-cream-recipe.html</NavigateUrl>
      <AlternateText>Vanilla IceCream</AlternateText>

   </IceCream>

</IceCreams>

<!--
**************************************************************************
* (C) Copyright 1992-2004 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
* Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
*                                                                        *
* DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
* best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
* development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
* to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
* no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
* programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
* and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
* consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
* furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
**************************************************************************
-->
```

Comment: Set the customErrors attribute to "Off" just like it's telling you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have still the same issue. I have already tried but there is not any differences.

Comment: What browser are you using? If it's IE, you have to explicitly enable JavaScript debugging in settings. Either way, use browser dev tools to identify any client-side errors.

Comment: I use Chrome, is it possible that this is server problem?

Comment: I'm more at home with server-side so I'll let someone else answer if the script is wrong. Can we see the code-behind?

Comment: That's the only code in .Net and another I have .xml file.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this task using Screenhero? As I have limited time to complete this assignment and I can not use anyone elses help.

Comment: Did you check the Dietel book's website for any errata?

Comment: I have checked but there is not any useful information about this error.

Comment: Can you please help me if i share my desktop to you via ScreeHero or TeamViewer? maybe you will be able to find the problem

Comment: I have added .xml file.

Comment: From what I can see the entire script section is all wrong. For starters:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script